# Pointer of a type point to a pointer of another

Tags: c++, pointers

I wonder if it is possible to make a pointer of (let's say) type A to point to a pointer of type B ? If it is possible then when you deference them they will show the same value? A=double B=int or viceversa?

Comment: This is called type casting: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: Lets say that i use reinterpret_cast to point pointer of type A to pointer of type B. When i dereference them they show different values even if they point to the same space in memory.How can i solve to show the same value when i deference them?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i only asked because i wanted to know the mechanism behind it.I wondered if a can point to a pointer with the same type it is possible to point to a pointer of another type.I succedd and when i display both of them i see that they have the same address.Porblem is they do not store the same value.Can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have

```
T* ptr1;   S* ptr2;
```

where `T` and `S` are two different, unrelated (by inheritance for example) types and want `ptr2` to point to `ptr1`

```
ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr1);
```

You *may not* do any access through `ptr2`, however, because it would break the [strict-aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: what do you mean by" access"? To deference?

Comment: @OtnielMercea By access it's meant that you may not read or write from/through that pointer. Dereferencing is a kind of read, so yes, too.

Comment: Would you explain me why not acces through it pls? I want to understand it much deeper.Pls

Comment: @OtnielMercea Have you read the answers in the other question I linked? If that's not enough (shouldn't be), take a look at [this](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if you have a base with A and B sub classes.
you can access A and B with base pointer and compiler will decide at run time which pointer to be executed.

```
class Base{
}

class A:Base{
}
class B:base{
}

int main(){
Base* ObjBase;
//accessing class A with Base pointer
ObjBase=new A(); 
//Accessing class B with Base pointer
ObjBase=new B();

}
```

This  is class polymorphism . you will often need it when you want to have a single array of base class having different child classes object

Comment: i assume that what i want to make is not possible for types like:double ,int long .....?

Comment: yups you can use void* ptr ... you can create methods in base that return int or double using method overriding .

Comment: and how to do it with void *ptr? I have no ideea

Comment: Does C have classes, polymorphism and `new`?

Comment: When a variable is declared as being a pointer to type void it is known as a generic pointer. Since you cannot have a variable of type void, the pointer will not point to any data and therefore cannot be dereferenced. It is still a pointer though, to use it you just have to cast it to another kind of pointer first.

Comment: c does not have classess but a guy from stack wanted to modify the tag so i did.The tag was first c++ but tat guy "corrected" me instead with c

Comment: and when you cast it to another type then you can deference?